# Jsplumb remove all connections not working with verion 2.4.3

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I am referring [this](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/dynamicAnchors/) example.

which uses jsPlumb version 2.4.3, I wanted to remove all connections but its not working, To remove all connection Ia am using this code.

```
jsPlumb.deleteEveryConnection().
```

To remove single connection I am using below code but it showing .detach is not a function.

```
 var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
     DragOptions: { cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 2000 },
     Container: "canvas"
  });

instance.bind("click", function (conn) {
    instance.detach(conn);
 });
```

Is there any version issue with jsplumb.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
         DragOptions: { cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 2000 },
         Container: "canvas"
      });
```

To Delete all connections try :

```
instance.deleteEveryConnection()
```

To remove single connection try:

```
instance.bind("click", function (conn) {
    instance.deleteConnection(conn);
 });
```